# Is there a way to upload jars for a dataflow job so we don't have to serialize everything?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

As an example, I remember in hadoop I could make classes serializable or give a path with the jars needed for my job.  I had either option.  I am wondering if this is true in a dataflow job such that I can have all the clients we have in jar files to be packaged for all the workers.

In our case, we have MicroserviceApi and a generated client, etc. and would prefer to output to that downstream microservice without having to make it serializable.

Is there a method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, let me clarify about serialization

When you add `implements Serializable` to a class in Java, you make it such that *object instances* of that class can be serialized (not the class itself). The destination JVM needs to have access to the class to be able to understand the serialized instances that you send to it. So, in fact you always need to provide the JAR for it.

Beam has code to automatically find all JARs in your classpath and upload them to Dataflow or whatever runner you're using, so if the JAR is in your classpath, then you don't need to worry about it (if you're using Maven/Gradle and specifying it as a dependency, then you're most likely fine).

---

2. Now, how can I use a class in Beam if it's not serializable?

In Beam, the more important part of it is to figure out *where* and *when* the different parts of the pipeline code will execute. Some things execute at **pipeline construction time** and some things execute at **pipeline running time**.

**Things that run at construction time**

- Constructors for all your classes (DoFns, PTransforms, etc)
- The `expand` method of your PTransforms

**Things that run at executuion time**

- For your DoFns: `ProcessElement`, `StartBundle`, `FinishBundle`, `Setup`, `TearDown` methods.

If your class does not implement serializable, but you want to access it at *execution time*, then you need to **create it at execution time**. So, suppose that you have a DoFn:

```java
class MyDoFnImplementation extends DoFn<String, String> {

  // All members of the object need to be serializable. String is easily serializable.
  String config;
  // Your MicroserviceApi is *not* serializable, so you can mark it as transient.
  // The transient keyword ensures that Java will ignore the member when serializing.
  transient MicroserviceApi client;

  public MyDoFnImplementation(String configuration) {
    // This code runs at *construction time*.
    // Anything you create here needs to be serialized and sent to the runner.
    this.config = configuration;
  }

  @ProcessElement
  public void process(ProcessContext c) {
    // This code runs at execution time. You can create your object here.
    // Add a null check to ensure it's only created once.
    // You can also create it at @Setup or @StartBundle.
    if (client == null) client = new MicroserviceApi(this.config);
  }
}
```

By ensuring that objects are created at execution time, you can avoid the need to make them serializable - but your configuration needs to be serializable.

Comment: What a GREAT answer, thank you!!!!    Now that I get that part, I had a follow on question I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076158/how-can-i-inject-with-guice-my-api-into-dataflow-jobs-without-needed-to-be-seria.   I will be digging into that ProcessContext hoping that can hold the api so I can mock it but any shortcuts on mocking MicroServiceApi would be fantastic in that next SO question I posted.

Comment: is there any way to not 'new MicroserviceApi' and inject it so I can swap a mock in?   ideally not one that requires 'static' fields because of the serialization issue.  perhaps a lookup or something?  or can the client of apache beam direct runner somehow access the client after setup?